# How to exclude dependency from compile but not from testCompile

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have a transitive compile dependency on old version of library testX. Library testX is not supposed to be compile dependency but testCompile dependency. What's more I'd like to depend on testX's newer version, not the older one.

I have a partial solution, which sets correct version of library but it works by overriding compile dependency. But I'm left with unwanted textX in compile.

```
compile group: 'x', name: 'testX', version 'new'
```

I tried excluding library testX from compile and adding explicit testCompile dependency but the exclude also removes dependencies from testCompile.

```
testCompile group: 'x', name: 'testX', version 'new'

configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'x', module: 'X'
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the entire project to resolve to a specific version by inserting the below command. Keep in mind, this will also force the transitive dependencies to resolve to this version in compile:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'x:testX:1.1.1'
  }
}
```